# Solve $(3y^4-11x^2y^2-28x^4)\,dx-(4xy^3)\,dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> I'm trying to solve the equation $$(3y^4-11x^2y^2-28x^4)\,dx-(4xy^3)\,dy=0$$

The equation is not exact i.e. $M_y \neq N_x$, also $\frac{M_y-N_x}{N}$ is not a function of $x$ alone , $\frac{N_x-M_y}{M}$ is not a function $y$ alone. If I separate the equation it becomes $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac34\frac yx-\frac{11}{4} \frac yx -7\frac{x^3}{y^3}$$
which after substituting $t=\frac yx$, we get $$ \frac{x dt}{dx} =-\frac{t}{4} -\frac{11}{4t}-\frac{7}{t^3}$$ which is quite difficult to integrate. I guess there should be a solution in implicit form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RHS is $\frac{-t^4-11 t^2-28}{4 t^3}$, so this is just
$$-\frac{4t^3}{t^4+11t^2+28}\,dt = \left(-\frac{16 t}{3 (t^2+4)}-\frac{28 t}{3 (t^2+7)}\right)\,dt = \frac{dx}{x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are going on right track. I'm continuing to solve from your last step.

$\begin{align}
\frac{xdt}{dx}&=-\frac{t^4+11t^2+28}{4t^3}\\
\int\frac{4t^3dt}{t^4+11t^2+28}&=-\int\frac{dx}{x}\\
\int\frac{2du}{u^2+11u^2+28}&=-\int\frac{dx}{x}\quad...(t^2=u)\\
\int\frac{2u+11-11}{(u+4)(u+7)}&=-\int\frac{dx}{x}
\end{align}$

Now, separate the terms on LHS by partial fraction.

$$\int\frac{1}{u+4}+\frac{1}{u+7}-\frac{11}{3}\left(\frac{1}{u+4}-\frac{1}{u+7}\right)dx=-ln(x)+c$$

I think you can proceed now by doing some elementary integrals.
**Note**:You can also write RHS as $-ln(xc)$ as $ln(c)$ is also a constant.